# Redirect URL with wildcard variables

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, wildcard

I am trying to use the htaccess file to redirect a url with random url variables for example:

somesite/news/training-viewdoc.htm?file=*somethingrandom*

to

somesite-two/news/training-viewdoc.htm?file=*that variable*

Any clues as to how to do this. Right now I have....

RedirectMatch 301 /news/training-viewdoc.htm?file=(.*) somesite-two/news/training-viewdoc.htm?file=$1

Comment: You should probably format your question to make it easier to read. Especifically the last part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't match against the query string in a `RedirectMatch`, however, it should automatically be appended so you don't need to worry about it:

```
Redirect 301 /news/training-viewdoc.htm somesite-two/news/training-viewdoc.htm
```

If you need to *only* redirect when there's a `file` in the query string, then you have to use mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^file=.
RewriteRule ^news/training-viewdoc.htm$ somesite-two/news/training-viewdoc.htm [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks! That works. Looks like I was making this harder than it needed to be.

Comment: @user3083872 You should click on the green checkmark so that your question is labeled as answered